# How to take input with spaces and convert it into a vector of int Without sstream

Tags: c++

I'm just trying to solve a question : [QUESTION](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14001)

So I did built most part of the code but stucked how to convert string with spaces that contain int to a vector of int without sstream as the time limit of question is 1 second, what is the most efficient way to do it.
My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
map<int, int> Solution(map<int, int> Stack, vector<int> cmnd, int height)
{
    int Pos = 1;
    bool IsBoxTaken = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < cmnd.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cmnd[i] == 0)
        {
            return Stack;
        }
        else if (cmnd[i] == 1 && Pos>=1)
        {
            Pos--;
        }
        else if (cmnd[i] == 2 && Pos<Stack.size())
        {
            Pos++;
        }
        else if (cmnd[i] == 3)
        {
            if(Stack[Pos]==0){continue;}
            if(IsBoxTaken==false)
                Stack[Pos] -= 1;
                IsBoxTaken = true;
        }
        else if (cmnd[i] == 4)
        {
            if(Stack[Pos]==height){continue;}
            if(IsBoxTaken==true)
                Stack[Pos] += 1;
                IsBoxTaken = false;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie();
    cout.tie();
    //Height
    int Height;
    //No. Of Stacks
    int StacksSize;
    cin >> StacksSize >> Height;
    //Map To Store Stacks
    map<int, int> Stack;
    for (int i = 1; i <= StacksSize; i++)
    {
        int Dat;
        cin>>Dat;
        Stack[i]=Dat;
    }
    string x;
    getline(cin,x);
    //Now I Want To Convert The String Into Vector of int
    vector<int>Cmnd;
    Stack = Solution(Stack, Cmnd, Height);
    for (int i = 1; i <= Stack.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << Stack[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `getline` you could use `while (cin >> x) { Cmnd.push_back(x); }`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp will it work if the user pressed enter after entering all the numbers?

Comment: Nevermind, I just read the description. `0` is always the last number: `while (cin >> x && x != 0) { Cmnd.push_back(x); }`

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= Stack.size(); i++)` is very fragile. Use a ranged for loop like `for (auto const& pair : Stack) { std::cout << pair.second << ' ';` } instead.

Comment: Your indentation in the `Solution` function is misleading.

Comment: Also please read or refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Questions need to be *self contained*. What happens if the link you have goes down, or the contents of that site changes? That could make your question totally worthless and impossible to help you with. Remember that this site isn't only for you right here and now, but also for others with similar (or the same) problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ohk I Won't Repeat It Again!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks!! Man It Worked Fine But Got TLE Lol.

Comment: Ok, it looks like your code requires the last 0 to be in the vector. So just add `Cmnd.push_back(0);` after the for loop that reads the numbers. Or change the algorithm to use the vector size instead.

Comment: I would change the function to accept references to the `map` and `vector` objects: `void Solution(map<int, int>& Stack, vector<int>& cmnd, int height)` This avoids making copies of the `map` and the `vector`.